# movement of a pole given displacement of endpoints

Tags: geometry

The center of a thin pole of length $d$ is at $(x1,y1)$. The pole is positioned so that if pushed, it would initially role in direction $\theta1$. (A vector perpendicular to the pole is pointing in direction $\theta1$.) A few moments later, we detect that the two ends of the pole have moved distances $w1$ and $w2$. Assume that in those few moments, each of the two ends of the pole moved at fixed rates. What is now the state of the pole: $(x2, y2)$ and $\theta2$?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming $w_1$ and $w_2$ are arc lengths rather than straight-line distances, and the pole is rolling, so at all times the velocity of the midpoint is perpendicular to the pole.
I'll also assume $w_1 < w_2$ (you can do the case $w_1 = w_2$ yourself).
 For convenience, represent the motion in the complex plane, with $z(t)$ the midpoint and
$z(t) \pm r e^{i\theta(t)}$ the endpoints.  We must have $z'(t) = v(t) i e^{i\theta(t)}$ where $v(t)$ is real.  The velocities at the endpoints are then $z'(t) \pm i r \theta'(t) e^{i\theta(t)} = (v(t) \pm r \theta'(t)) i e^{i \theta(t)}$, and by assumption $\dfrac{v(t) + r \theta'(t)}{v(t) - r \theta'(t)} = \dfrac{w_2}{w_1}$ is constant.  Solving this, we find $v(t) = c \theta'(t)$ where $c = r (w_1 + w_2)/(w_2 - w_1)$.  Then $z'(t) = i c \theta'(t) e^{i\theta(t)} = c \frac{d}{dt} e^{i\theta(t)}$.  Integrate this to get 
$z(t) = z(0) + c (e^{i \theta(t)} - e^{i \theta(0)})$.  Thus the midpoint of the pole is moving on a circle of radius $c$.  The endpoints $z(t) \pm r e^{i\theta(t)} = z(0) - c e^{i\theta(0)} + (c \pm r) e^{i\theta(t)}$ are moving on circles of radius $c \pm r = \dfrac{2 w_1 r}{w_2 - w_1}$ and $\dfrac{2 w_2 r}{w_2 - w_1}$.  When the first has gone through distance $w_1$, $(\theta(t) - \theta(0)) \dfrac{2 w_1 r}{w_2 -w_1} = w_1$ so
$\theta(t) - \theta(0) = (w_2 - w_1)/(2r)$.